# android 7.0 devices doesn't show logcat

Tags: android

when I run apps on android 7.0,I can't see the logcat. And when I click, the logcat just show:12-24 00:49:20.446 25656-25656/com.example.admin.myapplication I/HwPointEventFilter: ACTION_DOWN has not handle.
My Android studio version is 2.2.3

Comment: Please can you show a screenshot of the logcat window in Android Studio?

Comment: You need to open your SDK Manager and you need to install SDK Platform with respect to your Android version